# Making Switches Work in SSRS

Tags: ssrs, ssrs-2008-r2, report-builder

I'm trying to get my report to display different color cells, depending on the condition. This is my current code:

```
=Switch(Fields!DaysToExpiration.Value > 31, "Green",  
        Fields!User_Certification_Status.Value = 8, "Firebrick”,
        Fields!User_Certification_Status.Value = 13, “Orange”,
        Fields!User_Certification_Status.Value = 11, “Orange”,
        Fields!User_Certification_Status.Value = 10, “Orange”,
        Fields!User_Certification_Status.Value = 12, “Orange”,
        Fields!DaysToExpiration.Value <= 30, "Yellow", 
        1=1, "Gray")
```

So, my problem lies with the last part of the code. I'm using a matrix view, which means there are some cells where there is no data. SSRS is treating these like they have a value though (I'm assuming 0). This means that all the blank ones automatically turn to yellow, rather than gray. How can I get around this? 
Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, SSRS can be a little cumbersome with its handling of empty/null values. Try adding an explicit isnothing() before the yellow option:

```
=Switch(Fields!DaysToExpiration.Value > 31, "Green",  
    Fields!User_Certification_Status.Value = 8, "Firebrick”,
    Fields!User_Certification_Status.Value = 13, “Orange”,
    Fields!User_Certification_Status.Value = 11, “Orange”,
    Fields!User_Certification_Status.Value = 10, “Orange”,
    Fields!User_Certification_Status.Value = 12, “Orange”,
    IsNothing(Fields!DaysToExpiration.Value), "Gray",
    Fields!DaysToExpiration.Value <= 30, "Yellow", 
    1=1, "Gray")
```